# Flask - image issue - cannot str and numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

I am trying to capture image from picamera(RaspberryPi) and show it using Flask (on web), but I am facing this issue:

> b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
>
> TypeError:cannot concatenate 'str' and 'numpy.ndarray' objects

this is the code:

```
stream = io.BytesIO()
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera2:
    camera2.start_preview()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    camera2.capture(stream, format='jpeg')

data = np.fromstring(stream.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8)

frame = cv2.imdecode(data, 1)

yield (b'--frame\r\n'
       b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
```

Although I have read this Link, but it did not help me:
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask

outputs:

```
data = np.fromstring(stream.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8)
```

> [255 216 255 ..., 175 255 217]

and also

```
frame = cv2.imdecode(data, 1)
```

> [[[120 125 104] [120 125 104] [120 124 105] ...

any help would be highly appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trouble when you concatenate bytes string `b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'` with numpy array `frames`. In example as `frames` used bytes string, which read from jpeg file directly in binary mode.
I think you must not do anything with `stream.getvalue()`. it's return you ready data structure for streaming(jpeg file in bytes representation). so just use it

```
stream = io.BytesIO()
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera2:
    camera2.start_preview()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    camera2.capture(stream, format='jpeg')

yield (b'--frame\r\n'
   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + stream.getvalue() + b'\r\n')
```